# How to retrieve from mapping type ( I would like to retrieve struct elements from mapping)

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {

    event trace(address a);

    struct details { string name; uint roll ;} 

    mapping (address => details) public testMap;

    function set (string name, uint roll) {

        Student instance = new Student(name, roll);
        testMap[instance] = details(name,roll);

    }

    function get (address a) {

        testMap[a];

        // Here , from the mapping of address - I am trying to retrieve the struct and the corresponsing elements
    }
}


contract Student {

    function Student(string name, uint roll) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started. You can't return the complex struct type. You can enumerate the specific items to return.

Hope it helps.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {

  event LogNewStudent(address a);
  struct details { string name; uint roll ;} 
  mapping (address => details) public testMap;

  function set (string name, uint roll) {
    Student instance = new Student(name, roll);
    testMap[instance] = details(name,roll);
    LogNewStudent(instance);
  }

  function get (address a) 
    constant
    returns(string name, uint roll) 
  {
    // Here , from the mapping of address - I am trying to retrieve the struct and the corresponsing elements
    return(testMap[a].name, testMap[a].roll);
  }
}


contract Student {   
  function Student(string name, uint roll) {}    
}
```